# GADBannerView on SCNPlane possible?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, gadbannerview

I'm trying to display a GADBannerView in a SCNPlane. Code looks more or less like this:

```
let banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
banner.rootViewController = self
banner.load(GADRequest())

let viewMaterial = SCNMaterial()
viewMaterial.diffuse.contents = bannerView

let plane = SCNPlane(width: 320, height: 50)
plane.materials = [viewMaterial]

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
planeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 5, -10)

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

This kind of works but the banner is displayed like this, i guess the GADBannerView has some transparent stuff going on which is not handled correctly:
[image]

Is this even possibly? If yes how, if not why not. ;)

Comment: Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying `UIView` hierarchies as the `contents` of a `SCMaterialProperty` is not documented and not supported.

Comment: I guess so, a hackaround for static image ads worked for me by rendering the view as a UIImage and setting this as content of SCMaterialProperty, it´s even clickable.

Comment: mnuages :  Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?